# How to create a function using another function to output as many lines as characters in javascript? Ex: 4 lines of 4 "#". Basically, a square

Tags: javascript, function

Learning functions in javascript. The prompt is first to create a function called makeLine and then to use the makeLine function when making a makeSquare function. 
Here is my code for makeLine

```
function makeLine(size){
  for (let i = 0; i < size - 1; i++){
  hash= hash[i] + hash;
  }
    console.log(hash);
}
```

I've been trying to get the makeSquare function to use the makeLine function and I can get it show 16 #, but only all on the same line. When I try to use console.log and \n the console prints out undefined.

```
function makeSquare(squareSides){
   makeLine(squareSides*squareSides);

}

makeSquare(4);
```

Output I'm trying to achieve

```
####
####
####
####
```

This is just the skeleton of what i've been playing around with. I've tried a million different combinations, but this is the only way I've gotten the correct amount of #. I'm sure this is simple for anyone experienced, but I ran into a brick wall and the next exercises all depend on understanding this. All of the code that I seen related to this is a little above my head and the skills that we have learned up to this point.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my proposal for your `makeLine()` and `makeSquare()`:

```js
function makeLine (sideLength) {
  return '#'.repeat(sideLength);
}

function makeSquare (sideLength) {
  return Array(sideLength).fill(makeLine(sideLength)).join('\n');
}

console.log(makeSquare(16));
```

Note I'm using `Array(count)` to create an array of `count` length, then I use `fill()` to fill it with a value, and then I use `join()` to convert the array into a string, specifying a character to join the values.

An alternative for `makeSquare()` is to use `repeat()`, too, although you'll need a `\n` character and a `trim()` to clean the last one:

```js
function makeSquare (sideLength) {
  const line = makeLine(sideLength) + '\n';
  return line.repeat(sideLength).trim()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`String.prototype.repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) method to copy the same string multiple times to create a single line.

In `makeSquare` create lines in a loop and add them to an array. When all lines are in the array use [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to turn the array into a string with `\n` in between.

```js
const hash = '#';

function makeLine(size){
  return hash.repeat(size);
}

function makeSquare(size) {
  let lines = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    let line = makeLine(size);
    lines.push(line);
  }
  return lines.join('\n');
}

const square = makeSquare(4);

console.log(square);
```

Or you can make it really short by using arrow functions. `Array(size)` will create an empty array with a given size.

Together with [`Array.prototype.fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) you can fill that empty array with keys. The keys in this case being the result from the `makeLine` function. Then `join('/n')` the result together and you've got your square.

```js
const makeLine = size => '#'.repeat(size);
const makeSquare = size => Array(size).fill(makeLine(size)).join('\n');

const square = makeSquare(4);
console.log(square);
```